# How to create a static library with a Makefile from C source code

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to understand how to create Makefiles. I have the following Makefile:

```
DESTDIR=../../
PREFIX=../

STATIC=libdemo.a

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Winline -pipe

LDFLAGS = -L../../../lib
LIBS    = -lpthread 

SRC = demo1.c demo2.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

$(STATIC): $(OBJ)
        @echo "[Link (Static)]"
        @ar rcs $(STATIC) $(OBJ)

.c.o:
        @echo [Compile] $<
        @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ) *~ core tags *.bak Makefile.bak libgeniePi.*

.PHONEY:        install
install:        $(TARGET)
        @install -m 0755 libdemo.a  $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib

all:
        gcc -g -Wall -o program program.c $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Which almost does what I want. With `make` I create a static library out of the the files  `demo1.c` and `demo2.c`. With `make install` I place the library in  in the correct directory and with `make all` I finally compile my program that use4s this library which is all fine.

However, the library `libdemo.a` is executable which I don't think should be like that, right?

And second how can I make that all commands (`make`, `make install` and `make all`) will be run in sequence instead of calling them singly?

Comment: If you remove `libdemo.a` and rebuild it does it have executable permissions on the newly created file?

Comment: Typically, shared objects are read-execute and static libraries are just read. You can control those permissions in the install rule by changing 0755 to 0644.  Check out the man page for ```chmod``` for an explanation of those values and what they mean.

Comment: @Erik Ah, good catch, I totally missed the permissions being set via `install`.

Comment: ahh ok ok thanks ! now I understood thank you !

Comment: works thanks, wanna post it as an answer then I'll accept it

Comment: `make` is the same as `make all`

Comment: @RPGillespie No it isn't. `make` is the same as `make <first valid target>`. Which, in this case, is `libdemo.a` (from `$(STATIC)`).

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm in the habit of always putting `all` first and I guess I didn't realize it.

Comment: @RPGillespie See [Arguments to Specify the Goals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) in the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You chain targets through prerequisites.

To get what you want (and to have `make` do it by default) you need to add `install` as a prerequisite of your `all` target (though we'll be renaming that in a minute) and either replace `$(TARGET)` in the `install` prerequisite with `$(STATIC)` or replace `STATIC` with `TARGET` in the assignment and target lines.

Something like this:

```
DESTDIR=../../
PREFIX=../

STATIC=libdemo.a

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Winline -pipe

LDFLAGS = -L../../../lib
LIBS    = -lpthread 

SRC = demo1.c demo2.c

OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

$(STATIC): $(OBJ)
        @echo "[Link (Static)]"
        @ar rcs $@ $^

.c.o:
        @echo [Compile] $<
        @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJ) *~ core tags *.bak Makefile.bak libgeniePi.*

.PHONY: install
install: $(STATIC)
        @install -m 0755 $< $(DESTDIR)$(PREFIX)/lib

all: install
        $(CC) -g -Wall -o program program.c $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Also notice that I fixed your `.PHONEY` typo and used `$@`, `$^` and `$<` in place of explicit file/variable names in some of the recipes.

That said this will still leave `make all` rebuilding `program` from `program.c` *every* time you run `make all`.

To fix that you want to do this:

```
all: program

program: install program.c
    $(CC) -g -Wall -o $@ program.c $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

instead of your current `all` target.

Notice though that I couldn't use `$<` or `$^` in that recipe to refer to `program.c` because of the `install` prerequisite. Also note that this doesn't actually fix the "always rebuilding" problem (again because of the `install` prerequisite).

The fix for the rebuilding problem is to not have a phony target at all.

You can either use a real target for the copy instead or you can just let `-L` do its job and not bother with the local copy of `libdemo.a`.

```
all: program.c
    $(CC) -g -Wall -o $@ $< $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

But then again you aren't actually linking to `libdemo.a` anywhere here so I'm not sure what you are doing with it. (To link with it you would need `-ldemo` or to list `libdemo.a` in the linking command.)

Comment: Nicely re-worked, although the ```all``` rule is still using gcc directly instead of the CC macro. A minor nit.

Comment: the libdemo.a will be installed in `LDFLAGS` and then linked in `all` right?

Comment: @PaulBernhardWagner Where in `all` does it get linked? What part of the `gcc` command links it? Where do you tell `gcc` it should link it? Expand the arguments to `gcc` or look at the command that make runs and see if you can find it. You can find the path to the `lib` directory, sure. But what about the library itself?

Comment: I'm tempted to add that 'always installing software is often not a good idea'.  Especially with static libraries, where linking from the locally rebuilt copy is fine for testing.

Comment: @EtanReisner, you are right my bad sorry, it does not get linked, should be listed in `LIBS`