# Incorrect C Makefiles to generate library and main program?

Tags: c, makefile

Having a library and a main test driver in C, but although the library could be compiled successfully, the main test driver can't.

Here are the directory structures:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile$ ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 qxu  staff   96 Nov 23 13:19 include
drwxr-xr-x  6 qxu  staff  192 Nov 23 13:31 print_ascii_tree
drwxr-xr-x  5 qxu  staff  160 Nov 23 13:33 test_main_driver

qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile$ ll include/
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 qxu  staff  706 Nov 23 12:12 print_ascii_tree.h

qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile$ ll print_ascii_tree/
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 qxu  staff   250 Nov 23 13:31 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 qxu  staff  9122 Nov 23 12:12 print_ascii_tree.c

qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile$ ll test_main_driver/
total 16
-rw-r--r--@ 1 qxu  staff  616 Nov 23 13:33 Makefile
-rw-r--r--@ 1 qxu  staff  918 Nov 23 11:51 main.c
```

Here is the makefile for the library:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile/print_ascii_tree$ cat Makefile 
AR = ar -rcs
RM = rm -rf
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -I../include

libprint_ascii_tree.a: print_ascii_tree.o
    $(AR) libprint_ascii_tree.a print_ascii_tree.o

print_ascii_tree.o: print_ascii_tree.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c print_ascii_tree.c

clean:
    $(RM) *.o *.a
```

This library could be compiled smoothly:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile/print_ascii_tree$ make
gcc -I../include -c print_ascii_tree.c
ar -rcs libprint_ascii_tree.a print_ascii_tree.o
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile/print_ascii_tree$ ll
total 64
-rw-r--r--  1 qxu  staff   250 Nov 23 13:31 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 qxu  staff  7672 Nov 23 13:38 libprint_ascii_tree.a
-rw-r--r--  1 qxu  staff  9122 Nov 23 12:12 print_ascii_tree.c
-rw-r--r--  1 qxu  staff  7128 Nov 23 13:38 print_ascii_tree.o
```

Here is the Makefile for the test driver:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile/test_main_driver$ cat Makefile 
program_NAME := main.out

SRCS = main.c 
OBJS := ${SRCS:.c=.o}

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wextra -g

program_INCLUDE_DIRS := ../include
program_LIBRARY_DIRS := ../print_ascii_tree
program_LIBRARIES := print_ascii_tree

CFLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(program_INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(program_LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir))
LDFLAGS += $(foreach library,$(program_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

LINK.c := $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

.PHONY: all

all: $(program_NAME)

$(program_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.c) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.out
```

This is the error:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile/test_main_driver$ make
gcc -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wextra -g -I../include   -c -o main.o main.c
gcc -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wextra -g -I../include -L../print_ascii_tree -lprint_ascii_tree  -o main.out
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main.out] Error 1
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile/test_main_driver$ ll
total 32
-rw-r--r--@ 1 qxu  staff   617 Nov 23 13:39 Makefile
-rw-r--r--@ 1 qxu  staff   908 Nov 23 13:40 main.c
-rw-r--r--  1 qxu  staff  6496 Nov 23 13:40 main.o
```

Looks like `main.o` got compiled, but can't be linked with the library into the main executable?

Not sure what's wrong in the Makefile.

P.S. This is what's in `main.c`:

```
qxu@xqiang-mac-1:~/test/test_makefile/test_main_driver$ cat main.c
#include "print_ascii_tree.h"

int main()
{
    printf("asdf\n");
    // A sample use of these functions.  Start with the empty tree
    // insert some stuff into it, and then delete it
    NodePtr root;
    root = NULL;

    make_empty(root);

    printf("\nAfter inserting key 10..\n");
    root = insert(10, root);
    print_ascii_tree(root);

    printf("\nAfter inserting key 5..\n");
    root = insert(5, root);
    print_ascii_tree(root);

    printf("\nAfter inserting key 15..\n");
    root = insert(15, root);
    print_ascii_tree(root);

    printf("\nAfter inserting keys 9, 13..\n");
    root = insert(9, root);
    root = insert(13, root);
    print_ascii_tree(root);

    printf("\nAfter inserting keys 2, 6, 12, 14, ..\n");
    root = insert(2, root);
    root = insert(6, root);
    root = insert(12, root);
    root = insert(14, root);

    print_ascii_tree(root);

    make_empty(root);
}
```

Comment: Did you remember to define a function named `main` inside `main.c`?  Make sure there is no prepocessor macro named `main` because that would mess up the definition.  Maybe you should post your full code so we can check the definition of `main` too.

Comment: You should use `CFLAGS = -fsanitize=address -Wall -Wextra -g` and read the documentation of [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), of [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb), of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils)

Comment: @DavidGrayson Yes, I had one. Will update the post to reflect what `main.c` has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
$(program_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.c) $(program_OBJS) -o $(program_NAME)
```

you use `program_OBJS` variable, which is not defined. If you fix it to `$(OBJS)` or `$^`, then there is another problem with `LINK.c`. It is defined as:

```
LINK.c := $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

which means the resulting command will have library first and `main.o` second:

```
-lprint_ascii_tree main.o
```

and the linker won't find symbols used in `main.o`, which are defined in the library.

I'm not sure if you can make it work using separate `LINK.c` variable, but this should work:

```
$(program_NAME): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks for identifying the problems in this Makefile, danadam. I was not particularly familiar with Makefile and copied it from the answer to an old stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876275/how-to-create-a-static-library-with-a-makefile-from-c-source-code), but didn't realize that the answer still has something to be fixed.

Comment: Another question: is there a way to run `make` or `make clean` in the main test driver directory, so that all its dependencies are also made/cleared? I remember there is such a way, but can't get it on top of my head.  :(

Comment: That's probably not a recommended way but you could add `for d in $(program_LIBRARY_DIRS); do make -C "$${d}"; done` in the commands. Similar for clean.